# OR each binary with 0x20

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, math

I'm reading the algorithm of [google maps polyline encoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm). I can't understand step 8:

```
    00001 11111 10000 01010 00010 00001

8. OR each value with 0x20 if another bit chunk follows:

    100001 111111 110000 101010 100010 000001
```

Comment: All they want you to do is to set the sixth bit (identified by the bit mask 0x20) under some circumstances.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a leading one to each value except the last one.

From step 7:

`00001 11111 10000 01010 00010 00001`

Now read these as

`000001 011111 010000 001010 000010 000001`

ORing with `0x20` gives

`100001 111111 110000 101010 100010 000001`

which is what's in step 8.

(The last one isn't changed, because no "bit chunk" follows it.)

Answer (score 2):

Set the first bit of each chunk except the last chunk

Comment: by "first bit" one normally means the least significand bit. Please clarify.